# How to edit object like an array collection

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Hi seems it's a not best practice to iterate and edit object (not array). But is there a best way to to it as easy as it could be done with array of objects?

https://jsfiddle.net/woto/q9zqefq0/11/

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    object1: {
      'first': 'second'
    },
    object2: [
      {'key': 'first', 'value': 'second' }
    ]
}})
```

--

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">

  <!-- Is there a way to make it work? -->
  <!-- `k` value of object is not reactive(?) -->

  <div v-for="(v, k) in object1">
    <p> {{ k }} | {{ v }} </p>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="k">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="object1[k]">
  </div>

  <br />

  <!-- This works fine like a charm -->

  <div v-for="item in object2">
    <p> {{ item }} </p>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="item.key">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="item.value">
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: It's fine. Do you have a concrete problem?

Comment: Are you trying to update the object's property name?

Comment: @thanksd yes.
@dfsq yes. i want to use a name attribute on input to post it (without ajax request) like `<input ... name="'object1[' + k + ']'" value="v" >`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very silly thing to do, but if you really want to bind an object's property name to an input, you could do something like this:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    object1: {
      'first': 'second'
    },
    object2: [
      {'key': 'first', 'value': 'second' }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    updateObject(e, old, prop) {
      let val = this[prop][old];
      this.$delete(this[prop], old);
      this.$set(this[prop], e.srcElement.value, val);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">

  <div v-for="(v, k) in object1">
    <p> {{ k }} | {{ v }} </p>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" :value="k" @input="updateObject($event, k, 'object1')">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="object1[k]">
  </div>
  
  <br />
  
  <div v-for="item in object2">
    <p> {{ item }} </p>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="item.key">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="item.value">
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the first is that when you edit

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="k">
```

being `k` the key, you are simply editing `k` the string.

It does not reflect in the original object because that's not a reference to the name of the property. It is mere a string (that was extracted from the name of the property).